# Google API key error in ggmap even when specifying other source

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I've started using the package `ggmap` after a while again, now I'm encountering a problem when I try to fetch a map using the function `get_map`. No matter which source I specify, I always get the error

```
Error: Google now requires an API key.
   See ?register_google for details.
```

although I'm not sure why a call like

```
get_map(location = "texas", zoom = 6, source = "stamen")
```

Would need an API call to google. Has anyone experience something similar and is there a known workaround?

Comment: From the docs for the API key-related `ggmap` functions (e.g. `google_key`): "As of mid-2018, the Google Maps Platform requires a registered API key. While this alleviates previous burdens (e.g. query limits), it creates some challenges as well. The most immediate challenge for most R users is that ggmap functions that use Google's services no longer function out of the box, since the user has to setup an account with Google, enable the relevant APIs, and then tell R about the user's setup."

Comment: Yes, that's why I tried to circumvent this by using a different source such as stamen or OSM, but even then you get that error, and I don't know why you would need a google api call to get some OSM basemap. That's why this looks like a bug to me

Comment: Under the hood, `get_map` uses the google geocoding function to get the coordinates of that location, unless you provide the bbox object that `get_stamenmaps` would expect. Relevant part of the source code: https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/blob/37a86724bcf651ec0ef4be72db46d3ac2a03963a/R/get_map.R#L278

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @camille point out, this could be solve providing a bbox object which we can do with the package `{osmdata}`, function `getbb()`

In your case it would be:

```
pacman::p_load(ggmap, osmdata)
get_map(location = getbb("texas"), zoom = 6, source = "stamen")
```

**Conclusion:**

No need to create a google API key to retrieve a basemap from google map or openstreet maps. Hope it helps.